# Thread.interrupted is not working in java

Tags: java, thread-sleep

I read in oracle Docs for java as Thread.interrupted will bring back the Thread to non interrupted status.
*When a thread checks for an interrupt by invoking the static method Thread.interrupted, interrupt status is cleared. The non-static isInterrupted method, which is used by one thread to query the interrupt status of another, does not change the interrupt status flag.*

Please let me know whats going wrong because ,

```
if(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())
                {
                       flag = 999;
                       Thread.currentThread().interrupted();
                       System.out.println("Interruption cleared");
                }
```

Above block is not called at all.

```
public static void main(String args[]) 
{
    int n = 5;
    int flag = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    {

        try
        {
        System.out.println("i:"+i+":n:"+n+":Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted():"+Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted());           
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        if(i==(flag))
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();         

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()+"Exception :"+i);
            if(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())
            {
                   flag = 999;
                   Thread.currentThread().interrupted();
                   System.out.println("Interuption cleared");
            }

            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()+"Exception :"+i);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
i:0:n:5:Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted():false
i:1:n:5:Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted():false
i:2:n:5:Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted():true
falseException :2
falseException :2
i:3:n:5:Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted():false
java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at leo.threads.InterruptSleepMessages.main(InterruptSleepMessages.java:14)
i:4:n:5:Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted():false
```

Comment: You have written a terribly convoluted piece of code, as if your goal is to confuse yourself. Why not try something dead-simple? `currentThread().interrupt(); System.out.println(Thread.interrupted()); System.out.println(Thread.interrupted());`

Comment: Remember: Catching an InterruptedException also clears the status. You catch Exception, therefore also InterruptedException thrown by Thread.sleep when i=2. Then the status is cleared by catch and your if condition is false. So it _does_ work perfectly.

Comment: @Fildor ok I understood that Exception also clears interrupted status of the Thread.Thanks for you Explaination.It was useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I said in the comment was partly **wrong**. Actually Java 7 Docs sais:

> If this thread is blocked in an invocation of the wait(), wait(long),
>   or wait(long, int) methods of the Object class, or of the join(),
>   join(long), join(long, int), **sleep(long)**, or sleep(long, int), methods
>   of this class, then its interrupt status will be cleared and it will
>   receive an InterruptedException.

Source: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt()

So, the InterruptedException being thrown clears the status, not catching it.
Seen effect is the same. When i=1 the flag is set by `interrupt()` and executing `sleep` will lead to the flag being cleared and the exception thrown which leads to seen output.

Also see: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep(long)

Comment: Sorry @fildor its too late.Thanks for Answer